# Find element with special characters in attribute value

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have the following **html**:

```
<textarea class="input-validation-error form-control" cols="20" 
    data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid input" 
    data-val-regex-pattern="([a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][^\S\r\n]*\r\n)*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][\s]*" 
    data-val-required="Please enter valid values" 
    id="val" name="values" rows="9"></textarea>
```

I am trying to assert `element` for its validation:

```
expect(page).to have_css(
    "textarea[data-val-regex-pattern=([a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][^\S\r\n]*\r\n)*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][\s]*]")
```

but I keep getting `invalid selector` error. I have tried escaping the special characters also wrapping the whole value in both single and double quotes. What should this be asserted?

Comment: Does your test require that you match on the `data-val-regex-pattern`? It seems like that is one of the most difficult things to match on here. `id` is preferred since that __should__ be unique on the document.

Comment: @mrfreester I am not trying to find the element. The test is actually for input validations for which I need to check that the given element has the specified regex as the attribute value

Comment: My mistake, it takes my brain a minute to get out of routines sometimes :)

Comment: You mention you tried the single quotes, but this works for me when trying to match the element: `textarea[data-val-regex-pattern='([a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][^\S\r\n]*\r\n)*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][\s]*']`. Perhaps `.to have_css` is expecting something other than a standard **css selector**?

Comment: you might also try `expect(page).to have_css("textarea#val", :data-val-regex-pattern => "([a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-‌​9][^\S\r\n]*\r\n)*[a‌​-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA‌​-Z0-9][\s]*")`. Let me know if either of those works and I can post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @mrfreester. It didn't work. My accepted answer below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that you have to escape for both the ruby string and escape for CSS.  The character causing you the issues is the \ character which ends up needing to be double escaped, becoming \\\\

```
expect(page).to have_css('textarea[data-val-regex-pattern="([a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][^\\\\S\\\\r\\\\n]*\\\\r\\\\n)*[a-zA-Z][0-9]{11}[a-zA-Z0-9][\\\\s]*"]')
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It worked! I was expecting your response. You've pretty much answered all of my previous questions! Is there a simpler way to double escape this automatically? If the regex changes tomorrow then it will need to be checked again for any additions and again manually escaped.

Comment: @Rahul The issue is that you need double \ in the final CSS and even by switching to the single quote around the string in ruby you still need four \ to end up with 2 in the actual CSS query.  You could rewrite it as an xpath expression would would remove the need for the css escaping and use single quotes in ruby so you don't need double \.  Another option (depending on browser you're using) would be to use something like `selector = evaluate_script('CSS.escape(arguments[0])', selector)` to have the CSS.escape JS method handle the escaping for you, but you'll pay a performance penalty

Comment: @Rahul -- Forgot that I added a CSS escape method to Capybara a while back - so you could do `Capybara::Selector::CSS.escape(the_string)` to escape the string rather than evaluate_script

Comment: Thanks will give it a try.

Comment: Thomas, the CSS escape method worked and I like it much better. I have edited your answer for review. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
expect(page).to have_css("textarea[data-val-regex-pattern^='([a-zA-Z]'])
```